# How to debug fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `oid' for nil:NilClass
```

There seems to be something wrong with my fixtures. Is there some efficient way to track down the problem? (other than commenting the whole thing and uncommenting file by file to see what breaks)

Thanks

Comment: humm. Error stacktrace. I'll be online after 1 or 2 hours again. Ping me, I'll help you on this by debugging. By that time, if you are able to figure this out, Congo in advance! :)

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26137